# Linear system of differential equations given a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am asked to Give an example of a linear system for which $(e^{−t} , \alpha)$ is a solution for every constant $\alpha$ and to give the general solution for this system. I came up with a linear system based on my understanding,but it seems wrong to me, and I would like some guidance on how to approach this type of problem

From what I understand we can broadly describe a linear system of differential equations as 
$$x_1' = f(t,x_1,x_2)\\ x_2' = f(t,x_1, x_2)$$

and so since I am given the solution $(e^{-t}, \alpha)=(x_1(t), x_2(t))$, A linear system for which this is a solution can be given by

$$x_1' = -e^{-t}\\ x_2' = 0$$

but to me this appears too simple and incorrect. If so how do I go about approaching such a problem?

Comment: It seems that you think that $(e^{-t})'=-te^{-t}$.

Comment: apoligies, I will correct my error

Comment: Good, so you can consider the equation $x_1'=-x_1$.

Comment: Ah thank you, I understand now! I was complicating things for myself by assuming that the specific solution I was given could describe the entire system instead of being more general. Thank you!